# If $U_n \to U$ locally uniformly, and $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ is continuous and bounded, $gU_n \to gU$ locally uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

One of the exercises in the textbook ask me to prove that if $U_n \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ converges locally uniformly to $U \colon \mathbb{R} \to\mathbb{R}$ and $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded, then $gU_n \to gU$ locally uniformly.

I can prove the problem if I assume that $U_n$ is bounded.

Take finite interval $[a,b]$. Then $U_n$ converges uniformly to $U$ on $[a,b]$. Then $U_n$ is uniformly bounded. So we may consider $U_n \colon [a,b] \to [-M, M]$, and on $[-M,M]$, $g$ is uniformly continuous(as $g$ is continuous on a bounded interval) so $gU_n$ converges uniformly to $gU$.

But having the bounded assumption on $g$, I'm not sure how to prove the problem. (I think it may be false considering continuous function does not preserve uniform convergence in general, but I can't think of any counter-example)

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: By $gU$ do you mean the multiplication $(gU)(x)=g(x)\cdot U(x)$ or the composition $(gU)(x)=g(U(x))$?

Comment: @sranthrop I mean the composition.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the title and the author of your textbook? Just to see if there is anything more that could be useful in there.

Comment: @BrunoB It would be Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes by Resnick.

Comment: I wonder where the bounded hypothesis is supposed to intervene. So far the cases I've been able to prove on my draft, besides the one you gave, are: if $g$ is assumed uniformly continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$; or if $g \circ U$ is assumed to be continuous. Couldn't find an explicit counterexample either. Surely the author wouldn't make the first exercise of the whole book a wrong claim, but I'm as stuck as you are I'm afraid.

Comment: @BrunoB I do suspect there might be typos considering c) has typo since it has $g(U_n) \to g(U_n)$ instead of $g(U_n) \to g(U_0)$, and b) needs the further assumption that $U_0^1$ and $U_0^2$ are bounded, so there are typos in other places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is wrong, and here is a counterexample.

First, define $g_n(u):=\max\{0,1-2n|u|\}$ on $\mathbb R$ and set $g(u):=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}g_n(u-n)$. Then $g$ is bounded and continuous with $g(n)=1$ and $g(n+\frac{1}{2n})=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Geometrically, the function $g$ consists of "triangles" with height 1 centered at each natural number, and each triangle base is $1/n$ units long.

Now, set $U(x)=1/x$ for $x\neq 0$ and $U(0):=0$ and define $U_n(x):=U(x)+\frac{1}{2n}$. Then clearly, $(U_n)_n$ converges (even globally) uniformly to $U$. However, since
$$
g(U_n(1/n))-g(U(1/n))=g(n+\tfrac{1}{2n})-g(n)=-1
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the sequence $(g\circ U_n)_n$ does not converge locally uniformly to $g\circ U$.